# php timer facebook games

Tags: php, facebook

I have seen online php mmo's and Facebook games that have a timer when you upgrade certain things.  Like say I have a level 1 farm and I upgrade to a level 2 farm.  It counts down from say 14 minutes.  Then after the 14 minutes the upgrading process is complete.

How do they do this programatically speaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing some action, you take the current time + 14 minutes as target and save it somewhere. You do not unlock the new feature until this time is reached. You can display the remaining time using a simple `target time - current time`, which you can update dynamically on the client using Javascript.

Comment: Say you store the time task is to be completed on the server in a waiting things table.  Then must you run a scan through the entire table of waiting things to see which is finished each second?  This sounds intense.

Comment: That would be intense, but it's not necessary.  You just load all 'waiting things' from the db one time (say for that particular user) and then use client side code to know when time is up.  If new things require a wait, you add them server side so they can be re-fetched if needed.  If you want to be extra careful, when a waiting thing is *up* client side, you can double check it w/the server before deciding if it's really up or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with PHP (and other server-side languages). The only solution is to use client-side scripting languages like javascript or even Flash. I typically use jQuery along side javascript which is fairly easy to learn.